# React Native Navigation Wrap All Screens in a View

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Using react-navigation v5, how does one wrap all screens individually in a scroll view and a keyboard safe view?

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Test" component={TestScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Add ScrollView inside the HomeScreen and TestScreen component, not in App.js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside navigation container you are only allowed to use Navigator or Screen. So you cannot wrap `Stack.Screen` with any other component.

What you can do is wrap the screen component:

Create a new component `ScreenTemplate` maybe, you can decide the name. Then use this component to implement your keyboard avoid and scroll logic.

```
const ScreenTemplate = ({children}) => (
   <AnyWrapperComponent>
      {children}
   </AnyWrapperComponent> 
);
```

In any other screen:

```
const HomeScreen = () => (
   <ScreenTemplate>
     //implement anything you want
      <BlaBlaComponent />
    //etc..
   </ScreenTemplate>
);
```

Comment: Normal way is: `<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />`. Is there any way to pass `ScreenTemplate` directly to Screen `component` and specify its child (HomeScreen) ? To avoid repeating `<ScreenTemplate>` in all screens?